# Grep output based on regex: multiline with space bash

Tags: bash, sed, grep

I have the following output from my command. I am trying to extract the id from the text if possible as a one liner

```html
# module.mongodb_atlas.mongodbatlas_project_ip_whitelist.vpc-whitelist["10.3.0.3/17"]:
resource "mongodbatlas_project_ip_whitelist" "vpc-whitelist" {
    cidr_block = "10.3.0.0/17"
    comment    = "External access from '10.3.0.3/17' to the MongoDB Atlas"
    id         = "dffgsgsnk=:sdgsdg=-cHJvamVjdF9pZA==:sdfsdfs"
    project_id = "sdsdss"

    timeouts {}
}
```

I am trying to get the id from the above text using bash.

I tried converting the output to json but it did not work as the output can have different formats which would make it difficult.

`echo $json| tail -n +3 | sed 's/[[:blank:]]//g'` i removed the empty space. But the sed part of extracting the id= hasnt worked.

```
echo $json| tail -n +3 | sed 's/[[:blank:]]//g' | sed -e '/id=/!d'
```

I also tried different ways of grep to get the id but nothing worked. Everything gave an empty string. `grep`with id would give me 3 lines as output so i need id= to be the matching string

`echo $json| tail -n +3 | sed 's/[[:blank:]]//g' | grep 'project_id'`

> project_id="dfgdfg"

`echo $json| tail -n +3 | sed 's/[[:blank:]]//g' | grep '="'` (Once i add `id="` here nothing comes up)

> cidr_block="10.3.0.3/17"
> comment="Externalaccessfrom'10.3.0.3/17'totheMongoDBAtlas"
> id="ZW50cnk=:fdgdfg=-dfg==:dg"
> project_id="dfgdfg"

Comment: Maybe `sed -n 's/^ *id *= *"\([^"]*\).*/\1/p' <<< "$json"`?

Comment: [It works](https://ideone.com/gFIrEt).

Comment: Have you used the same code as I suggested? You can see the output is as expected. If there are TAB chars, replace spaces with `[[:space:]]`: `sed -n 's/^[[:space:]]*id[[:space:]]*=[[:space:]]*"\([^"]*\).*/\1/p' <<< "$json"`. And again [it works](https://ideone.com/BgaUIC).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I have tried it on different inputs and it seems to work sometimes with the same input and not always. https://ideone.com/i7WXOh i have added an example where it doesnt. I have tried it on zsh and bash terminal.

Comment: But in that string there are no lines and `id` starts somewhere in the middle. Then use `sed -n 's/.*[[:space:]]id[[:space:]]*=[[:space:]]*"\([^"]*\).*/\1/p' <<< "$json"`

Comment: The output of json is multiline when i run it on mac terminal (zsh) and single line when i do it on bash. But with the last sed command, the id that was retrieved was the cluster_id. so basically the forst id on the input

Comment: And what is the rule for that case then?

Comment: I can take that i m always executing the terraform commands on bash so that the result is not multiline when saved to the variable. i also tried passing on the value directly to the sed command which also did not work (i see the output on bash console as multiline eventhough its single line after saved to a var)

Comment: Ok, I understand that you do not use `"$json"`, but you use `$json`. Of course it is single line, all line breaks are removed if you do not quote the variable

Comment: when i did echo i did not use "$json" but with the sed command i did use the `"$json"` i m gonna try this in a script to see if it works. will update asap once i have a result.

Comment: So, what is the status? I think you should either update or delete the question, it is not possible to give the definitive answer in its current form.

Comment: I m sorry, I got sick and couldnt reply.  the sed did not work and i figured out coz sed behaves differently on mac bash and zsh terminals.

Comment: Are you using `zsh`? Could you please precise?

Answer (score 0):

using awk, without converting it to json:

```
awk '/\yid\y/ { gsub(/"/, "");print $3}' file
```

- `/\yid\y/` exact match of the id word
- `gsub(/"/, "")` quotes removal
- `print $3` print the id field

Comment: `echo "$json" | awk '/\yid\y/ { gsub(/"/, "");print $3}'` no output

Comment: it works with the file no .json is needed